# Using a 'for' loop in batch file programming to display the first N natural numbers

Tags: windows, loops, windows-xp, batch-file, for-loop

I would like to mainly know the working of a `for` loop. For this I think a small sample program will be helpful to me. So what is a simple program to display the first N natural numbers?

Comment: There's a plenty of examples: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch%5D+for+loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are talking about Windows batch programming here you have a natural numbers generator:

```
for /L %i IN (0,1,9) do @echo %i
```

Other helpful links to deal with files and so on:

- http://www.computerhope.com/forhlp.htm
- http://ss64.com/nt/for.html

If you are talking about GNU Linux/Unix bash scripting you can go to:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for the earlier reply. /L stands for what? Please reply.

Comment: Look at "FOR /?" for help.  /L does a sequence from "start" to "end" in increments of "step".  In this case, from 0 to 9 in steps of 1.  Official syntax: "FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]"

Comment: @sarika: `/l` or `/L` is for *loop*. Easy, ah?